# PyInstaller problems

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, exe

Python 3.8 32bit, PyInstaller 5.13

After build with specific .spec file I get this output after opening file: (it is debug mode and console mode in pyinstaller)

```
[8780] PyInstaller Bootloader 5.x
[8780] LOADER: executable is D:\sh2017-2\dist\fond\fond.exe
[8780] LOADER: homepath is D:\sh2017-2\dist\fond
[8780] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
[8780] LOADER: archivename is D:\sh2017-2\dist\fond\fond.exe
[8780] LOADER: Cookie found at offset 0x32E81C
[8780] LOADER: No need to extract files to run; setting extractionpath to homepath
[8780] LOADER: SetDllDirectory(D:\sh2017-2\dist\fond)
[8780] LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
[8780] LOADER: Python library: D:\sh2017-2\dist\fond\python38.dll
[8780] LOADER: Loaded functions from Python library.
[8780] LOADER: Manipulating environment (sys.path, sys.prefix)
[8780] LOADER: sys.prefix is D:\sh2017-2\dist\fond
[8780] LOADER: Pre-init sys.path is D:\sh2017-2\dist\fond\base_library.zip;D:\sh2017-2\dist\fond\lib-dynload;D:\sh2017-2\dist\fond
[8780] LOADER: Setting runtime options
[8780] LOADER: Initializing python
[8780] LOADER: Overriding Python's sys.path
[8780] LOADER: Post-init sys.path is D:\sh2017-2\dist\fond\base_library.zip;D:\sh2017-2\dist\fond\lib-dynload;D:\sh2017-2\dist\fond
[8780] LOADER: Setting sys.argv
[8780] LOADER: setting sys._MEIPASS
[8780] LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
[8780] LOADER: extracted struct
[8780] LOADER: running unmarshalled code object for struct...
[8780] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py
[8780] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pywintypes.py
[8780] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pythoncom.py
[8780] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pkgutil.py
[8780] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_inspect.py
[8780] LOADER: Running pyi_rth__tkinter.py
[8780] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py
[8780] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py
[8780] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pywintypes.py
[8780] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pythoncom.py
[8780] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pkgutil.py
[8780] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_inspect.py
[8780] LOADER: Running pyi_rth__tkinter.py
[8780] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py
[8780] LOADER: Running conv.py
[8780] Failed to unmarshal code object for conv
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
[8780] LOADER: OK.
[8780] LOADER: Manually flushing stdout and stderr
[8780] LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
```

And application don't open.

Is it some error or what I do wrong?

Comment: PyInstaller 5.13 has lots of bugs and most of references suggest installing an older version of it(which didn't work for me)
I had bunch of similar problems like pyiboot01_bootstrap and _bootlocale
then i found nuitka as an alternative and i believe its a way better tool.
give it a try, that may solve your problem.